# Remotely collect server data using Net::OpenSSH

Tags: beginner, perl, ssh, status-monitoring

I am newbie in Perl programming and currently trying to use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) module in my code.  My code as below which the task is to run multiple commands in remote server:

```
foreach $s (@servers) {
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$username\@$s", timeout=>30);
$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect: " . $ssh->error;
print "Connected to $s\n";

my $fh = $ssh->capture("df -k /home/ | tail -1") or die "Unable to run command\n";
my @df_arr = split(/\s+/, $fh);
print "$s:  Disk space /home/ = $df_arr[3] \n";

my $fh1 = $ssh->capture("svmon -G -O unit=GB | grep memory") or die "Unable to run command\n";
my @sv_arr = split(/\s+/, $fh1);
print "$s:  Free memory = $sv_arr[3] \n\n";

close $fh;
undef $ssh;
}
```

This code is not so nice since I plan to simplify and reduce a line as many as possible.

Are there any techniques or methods that I can use to simplify this code?

Comment: Why not use standard tools, such as [SNMP](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net), instead of writing your own hacks?

Comment: SNMP is a hard to manage, but there are a slow of alternatives for this that have more history and ease of use like nagios, OMD, or munin.  I'm assuming this question is just a learning exercise and not the beginnings of a new monitoring system.

Comment: This exact same question/code was posted [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1198771) on September 6, 2017 12:28 UTC. Is it *your* code?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Hi, Im not posting my code to that website...it seem someone post it there.

Answer (score 5):

Looks good to me. Kudos for the "... or die" idiom. More informative output would be "unable to run df on $s" or "unable to run svmon on $s".

You don't have to do `tail` or `grep` on the far end, as a line of perl could do that. But it is a perfectly clean and sensible approach, which I advocate keeping.

If you wind up with many such monitoring commands, you may find it convenient to move the post-processing into perl commands that can be refactored out as utility functions.

Comment: I can only add that proper indentation and more verbose variable names would improve legibility.